# Is there a way I can swap out member variables without passing them individually in a child constructor?

Tags: c++, class, virtual

I have classes as follow:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual int ReturnX()
        {
            return x;
        }

    private:
        int x = 5;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    private:
        int x = 10;
};
```

and code as follows:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    std::cout << b->ReturnX() << std::endl;
}
```

I understand that if I override `ReturnX` in `Derived` then the base pointer will correctly use the proper `ReturnX` but how do I get it to use the proper `x` value? I would like the line to return 10.

The reason i don't want to just pass it in the constructor is that I have many (10+) multidimensional `std::arrays` like `x` and passing them individually into the constructor is very tedious.

Comment: The behaviour of the program is undefined because the unique pointer destroys the object through a base pointer and the destructor of the base class is non-virtual.

Comment: Show an example of the "tedious" program so that we can understand the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you want to access Derived's x, you need to override the ReturnX function and to specify it.

Comment: @John if the function is the same, is there a way to use 'using' to just redefine it without copying and pasting code?

Comment: @eerorika there are multiple multidimensional std:array like so std::array<std::array<double, 100>, 10>, 10+ of them. The classes aren't different except for the variable values. I understand that this isn't the point of polymorphism but for code readability I'd like to make them different classes.

Comment: @John of course, I understand now that the base pointer cannot access a child class member variable. Is there a way to use the `using` keyword to copy the method to the derived class?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The child class inherits the function, but if you want it to do something else, then you need to override the function and tell it what to do.

Comment: Firstly, your question has no solution as asked - class `Base`, and its member functions like `ReturnX()` have no awareness that they may be an instance of class `Derived`, so there is no means for `Base::ReturnX()` to access a member of `Derived`.      Second, if you have a "many" multi-dimensional arrays in either class `Base` or in class `Derived`, you have a flawed design anyway.  So, essentially, you're asking for a work-around that doesn't exist for a flawed design.   That is a classic XY problem - you need to step back and work out how to rationally manage the data your classes need.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: Construct base class members according to a policy provided by the derived class

Here, the base class is provided a policy by the base class. This policy basically just contains functions that return what the initial values of the members should be.

```
class Base {
    int x;
    std::string y;
   public:
    struct DefaultPolicy {
        int getX() { 
            return 5;
        }
        std::string getY() {
            return "Hello"; 
        }
    }; 
    
    virtual int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    virtual std::string getY() {
        return y;
    }

    template<class Policy>
    Base(Policy&& p) 
      : x(p.getX())
      , y(p.getY())
    {}

    // By default, Base uses the DefaultPolicy
    Base() : Base(DefaultPolicy()) {}

    virtual~Base() = default; 
};
```

Now, we can write a derived class that uses a given policy:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    // This is our policy
    struct Policy {
        int getX() {
            return 10; 
        }
        std::string getY() {
            return "Hello, world!"; 
        }
    };

   public:
    Derived() : Base(Policy()) {}
};
```

#### Solution 2: Make base an interface with members accessible through a virtual function

Here, we have `Base` be an abstract class that has no member variables:

```
class Base {
   protected:
    virtual int& x_() = 0; 
   public:
    virtual int getX() {
        return x_();
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default; 
};
```

Then, we can create separate derived classes based on the initial values and other stuff:

```
class Derived1 : Base {
    int x = 5;
   protected:
    int& x_() override {
        return x;
    }
};
class Derived2 : Base {
    int x = 10;
   protected:
    int& x_() override {
        return x;
    }
};
```

#### Solution 3: use defaulted constructor arguments

Would it be possible to do something like this?

```
class Base {
   protected:
    int x;
   public:    
    Base(int x_ = 5) : x(x_) {}

    virtual int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default; 
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
    Derived(int x_ = 10) : Base(x_) {}
};
```

When you use it, you don't have to specify a value for `x` when creating `Derived`, and it works as intended:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    // Prints 10
    std::cout << b->getX() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the value of x in the base class, but what he wants is to have a member in the inherited class that is accessible in the base class which isn't possible afaik.

Comment: I specifically don't want to pass the values into the constructor as there are quite a few std::array<std::array, 100>, 10> which is incredibly ugly to look at.

Comment: I provided two other solutions. Solution 1, the policy one, is the most general case one and hopefully solves your problem